# Image in LaunchScreen.xib not showing after upgrade to Xcode 7 & iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

After upgrade to Xcode 7 and iOS 9, the image in LaunchScreen.xib sometimes not showing up. If I change the name of the Image Set, It **will** appear in the next few builds, but after a few builds, it disappeared again, I didn't change any code or project settings. Anyone encountered the same issue? Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I can't localize the xib of launchscreen. And if I try to localize an image inside the launchscreen, it fails too -_-

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but found that if I put the image inside an asset catalog it worked fine.